# bootstrap navbar two "hamburger menu" left and right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar

I really did my research but haven't found anything, I've seen items on left and right and then collapsed to "hamburger menu" on right, or left. But I haven't seen two collapsed menu on each side, which is what I'd like to do.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

And collapsed:

[image]

So, firt of all I'd like to have the real "hamburger menu" on the left when not collapsed, I tried to add it but I got only one white line.

Second, I'd like to have the person icon with the text "about us", but when collapsed I want only the person icon to appear.

So the final result would be like this:

[image]

The hamrbuger menu would be clickable but won't drop any menu down.

Is this even possible to do? I'm new to bootstrap and as I said before I did my research but couldn't fint anything realted to something like this.

ps: the hamburger menu on left is not crucial, I can live with the glyphicon.

this is my code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span> calcular.cl</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menú</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Acerca de nosotros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

and my CSS:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0px;} /* esto quita el margen del navbar*/
.navbar-brand {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
 }

  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border-color: #d35400; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ecf0f1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffe6d1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffe6d1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffe6d1;
    background-color: #d35400; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a:focus {
    color: #ffe6d1;
    background-color: #d35400; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a .caret,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a:hover .caret,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffe6d1;
    border-bottom-color: #ffe6d1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #ecf0f1;
    border-bottom-color: #ecf0f1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffe6d1;
    border-bottom-color: #ffe6d1; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #d35400; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #d35400; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ecf0f1; }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;   }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffe6d1;
    background-color: #d35400;   }
  }
```

Hope you don't think im lazy but this is my second day trying to do this.

Comment: could you please paste it in jsbin and the paste the link here so that we can look a working copy?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but only an idea for two separate collapsible menus:

1. Place both toggle-buttons in the `navbar-header` block.
2. Wrap left side of the navbar into separate `collapse navbar-collapse` block.
3. Be carefull with the `float` property.

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/kXAYGz

```css
.navbar-toggle.pull-left {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-left {
    float: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseLeft" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseRight" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-sm-left" id="collapseLeft">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Left 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Left 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Left 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseRight">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Right 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Right 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Right 3</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```